# Disable and Enable button conditionally based on scroll position?

Tags: jquery, validation, button, scroll, submit

I am working on a TERMS OF USE page. I have two button (Agree and Decline) and want them  to be unlocked until the user scrolls to bottom of that container. Could anyone help me fix my code please ? Thanks!

```
<div id="container_terms" name="container_terms">
    TEXT
    TEXT
    TEXT
</div>
<p align="center">
<input type="button" name="agree" class="agree" value="Agree" disabled />
<input type="button" name="decline" class="decline" value="Decline" disabled/>
</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementsByName("container_terms")[0].addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollHeight, false);

        function checkScrollHeight(){
            var agreementTextElement = document.getElementsByName("container_terms")[0] 
            if ((agreementTextElement.scrollTop + agreementTextElement.offsetHeight) >= agreementTextElement.scrollHeight){
                document.getElementsByName("agree")[0].disabled = false;
            }
        }

</script>
```

Comment: You want your user to be able to click them *until they can be seen*? Why?

Comment: I hope you typed that out backwards...

Comment: No, I want the buttons to gray out until user scrolls to bottom. So he won't be able to click on the buttons until he scrolls to bottom of the container

Comment: But surely the user can't click on the buttons anyway, until they're visible? I could understand disabling buttons until the user has checked a checkbox (or affirmatively interacted in some other way), but this seems pointless.

Comment: YES they are visible!! you could scroll down only inside the container but the buttons are fixed in the page

Comment: the container is under: overflow: scroll;

Comment: Now, if you'd included that in your question it would have made more sense. So: disable the buttons until the user has (presumably) read the terms and conditions?

Comment: Yessss Thats exactly what I mean :) I just used another function but still not working....

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to ensure they have scrolled to the bottom of the page before the buttons are enabled...  replace this:

```
if ($win.scrollTop() == 0)
```

with this:

```
if($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() == $(document).height())
```

Comment: I just replaced it but still not working.. just used a different code above and still not working. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: what browser are you using where this isn't working?  what version of jquery?

I'll ask the silly question - if the user has to scroll to the bottom of the text area to even see the buttons, then what is the difference between having them disabled as you request - or them just not being visible?  either way achieves the same thing.  you could 'dock' the buttons to the bottom and disable until the scroll was complete, I suppose...

Comment: I am using chrome and its not working in my local file I still haven't upload it to the server. Well the buttons are fixed in the page only the text u can scroll.. I am using 1.10.3 jquery
I just copied an exact tutorial shown above using pure js but still not working :(

Comment: if the buttons are truly fixed on the page, it would help if you had the accompanying CSS that fixed them.  if you can post the page, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use clientHeight in your comparison.

```
(agreementTextElement.scrollTop + agreementTextElement.clientHeight) >= agreementTextElement.scrollHeight
```

scrollHeight and clientHeight take into account the contents and padding of the container, while offsetHeight also includes borders and vertical scrollbars.

I created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs3prkfm/) which seems to work well for me.

Also note that in your handler, you're only getting the agree button and not the decline button for enabling.